# Makefile: assume file is up to date for a specific target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using GNU Make to build graphs for a paper. I have two targets:

- `data` which rebuilds the data/*.csv folder. This is **very** computationally expensive. (Also in terms of money.)
- `plot` which rebuilds the plots from the data/ folder

Now, because of how expensive `data` is to compute, I committed the resulting files in git. I'd like to avoid changing them whenever possible. But when someone clones the git repository, it messes the mtime of the files, so `make plot` wants to rebuild `data`, even though they're already there.

That said, I don't want to remove the target dependency! If, for some reason, I recompute something in `data`, I want the plots to see that and to be able to rebuild themselves. Also, if one csv is missing, I want it to be computed.

I think ideally, what I want is to have a way to say "if these files are present, assume that they are up to date". Is there a way to do that in GNU Make?

Comment: What you are looking for may be [order-only dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

Comment: Ah, great! You should have posted that as an answer, because it's definitely the solution.

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer because I am almost sure this question has already been answered before (but I did not take time to find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Renaud Pacalet, I used [order-only dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) to rewrite my rule like this:

```
data/%.csv: | source/%.py
    ...
```

Using this `|` allows `make` to never rebuild a CSV file already present.